# How to put the hash value at the end of the static resources built when vite is packaged

Tags: vite, rollup

**Vue Version**
^3.2.47

**Vite Version**
^4.1.4

How to put the hash value at the end of the static resources built when vite is packaged.

Trying to put the hash value at the end, but the build reports an error

```
assetFileNames: "static/[name][extname]?[hash]"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use special charachters in filename

When translating in Vite, a file is generated. By default, the file name cannot contain special characters such as `?`. Therefore, if you remove and/or replace it (to `-` or another) with an accepted character, it should work.

-- However, I don't understand why it's good if the file extension drifts into the middle of the file, losing its meaning.

### Example

```js
assetFileNames: "static/[name]-[extname]-[hash]"
// Result: "myFileName-svg-21b4adfd"
```